# Elusive meaning of "affects"

Tags: meaning

> Pandit affects a down-to-earth demeanor.

What does *affect* mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Affect* in this sense means to "use, wear, or assume (something) pretentiously or so as to make an impression oin others: *an American who had affected a British accent* " [Webster's]

In your sentence it means Pandit was pretending to be "just one of the guys."

Comment: Indeed. Its usage in this sense is pretty rare however (at least in British English).